# Call to a member function load() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225

Tags: php, magento

Reading this tutorial  http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm
Working from Last 3 Days,Please Help if u can

But i am getting this error:-

Loading the blogpost with an ID of 1
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on boolean in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Weblog/etc/config.xml

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>
                Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model
            </class>
            <resourceModel>
                weblog_mysql4
            </resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <weblog_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_write>
        <weblog_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Weblog/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function testModelAction() {
    $params=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $blogpost=Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
    echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
    $blogpost->load($params['id']);
    $data=$blogpost->getData();
    var_dump($data);
} } ?>
```

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Weblog/Model/Mysql4/Blogpost.php

```
<?php
class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
}   } ?>
```

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php

```
<?php
class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
} } ?>
```

Comment: What does the `$blogpost` variable contain?

Comment: By attempting to retrieve a weblog/blogpost Model, you told Magento to instantiate a class with the name

Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Blogpost

Comment: Yes, but what does it actually contain when you `var_dump` the contents of `$blogpost`? And please check your log and exception files.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `blog_posts` (
  `blogpost_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text,
  `post` text,
  `date` datetime default NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`blogpost_id`)
)                                                                                                   INSERT INTO `blog_posts` VALUES (1,'My New Title','This is a blog post','2009-07-01 00:00:00','2009-07-02 23:12:30');

Comment: array
  'blogpost_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'title' => string 'My New Title' (length=12)
  'post' => string 'This is a blog post' (length=19)
  'date' => string '2009-07-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  'timestamp' => string '2009-07-02 16:12:30' (length=19)

Comment: It should contain This Array

Comment: And Chris About Logs,it is not creating any system.log and exception.log file

Comment: @BLalji i have added answer please check

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <weblog_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_write>
        <weblog_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

> model and resource model should be on same line